# Immigration to Canada requirements

Tags: visa, immigration, canada

I know an adult Lebanese that wants to immigrate to Canada, and I just want to know what are the requirements for him to do so. Does he need a Visa? Does he have to pay for anything? What are the general requirements for him to immigrate to Canada?

Answer (score 4):

With more than 60 different Canadian visa categories, yes, he may be able to immigrate to Canada and, yes, there may be a fee.  Without knowing specifics, it's difficult to provide anything but a general answer. It would be better to use the [Government of Canada Immigration and Citizenship tools](http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/getting-started.asp) to determine whether your friend is eligible, what type of visa, how much it will cost, and how to apply.

> **Find out if you are eligible to apply**
>
> Do you want to work, study, visit, travel through or live permanently in Canada?
>
> Answer a few questions to find out what immigration programs you can apply for. Each immigration program has different application and eligibility requirements. You will need about 10-15 minutes to complete the form.
>
> You may be asked questions about your:
>
> - nationality
> - age
> - language ability
> - family members
> - education
> - work experience
> - income and/or net worth
> - details on any job offer
>
> Based on your answers, we will tell you what programs you may be eligible for, so be as accurate as you can.
>
> If you are eligible, we will give you a detailed list of instructions on what to do next.