# Requirements for US retiree to move to Canada

Tags: canada, residency

We’re not *planning* to move to Canada, but we’re curious  about the requirements.  A [government website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/come-canada-tool.html) has a multiple-choice app to tell you if you’re eligible. But it won’t work unless you have a specific province in mind.  One of the questions is “what do you want to do here” but the menu does not offer “live as a retired person on pensions and social security.”  I've heard there are "[sixty different visa categories](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/9264)" which suggests that web app is oversimplified.

What are the requirements?  Not quite curious enough to pay a lawyer just to ask.

Comment: The choices presented apparently depend on the user's inputs. I just gave it a try, and was stopped when there was no "live in Canada in retirement" choice in a drop-down. Up to that point, I hadn't been asked to specify a province.

Comment: Unfortunately, immigration has been partly devolved to the provinces so it matters.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, right.  I tried all the options on that question, and picked BC on the other one, answered the rest truthfully, and got "not eligible."  But since "retire" wasn't an option, no way to tell whether that applies.  I've asked some Canadian friends, but since they're not immigration lawyers, not likely they can answer.  I may have to call the consulate and hope I don't get someone hostile.  (I'd really prefer Spain, but they don't seem to be very anxious to get my money!)

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you either have a relative in Canada who can sponsor you for immigration or can spend over six months every year elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think so, either, but that's only based on the difficulty of finding a mention of retirement.  Since some other categories allow you in based on proving sufficient income, seems illogical to ban retirees with sufficient income.  As for six months in/six months out, that's EASY to do.  But I've read claims that you can leave for one day and return for another six months.

Comment: The actual immigration requirement is six months per visit, as in the UK and the US, so considering that requirement alone, yes, it is possible to leave and return immediately for a new six-month period.  The problem is that after you do that once or twice, they're not going to let you back into the country, because you don't have valid long-term resident status.

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me, and it's not something I want to do anyway.  But I hear that some people are getting away with it.